# Usefulness of --from-code in command iconv

Tags: character-encoding

Is the `--from-code` option of the `iconv` command useful (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html)?

I mean, I don't see any difference if I specify this parameter (`--from-code 'iso-8859-1'` or not with the command below:

```
iconv --from-code 'iso-8859-1' --to-code "utf-8"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html):

> If no *from-encoding* is given, the default is derived from the current locale's character encoding.

So it's required only if the current locale's encoding doesn't match the encoding you're converting from. It's useful in any situation where that's not the case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't catch this information (about current locale's character encoding).
Thanks for your answer.